# How to reliably update data on a particular RecyclerView Item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The date/time in my RecyclerView Item only updates every other time I change it, not for every change. The current process is:

- User updates time via Date/TimePicker
- Change is saved to Room database
- My fragment's "reminders" LiveData observer is triggered, which calls the adapter's overridden submitList function
- For every ~2nd change, submitList thinks the old and new lists are identical, because the old list is somehow already updated to reflect the new changes even though the old list (mRemindersList) is private to the Adapter so I'm not sure how it's getting sneakily updated.

**Example:**

I changed the time from 15:21 to 21:21. After hitting OK on the below dialog, the RecyclerView Item still shows the old time of 15:21:
[Picture of RecyclerView Item whose time is 15:21 while the new time selected is 21:21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr1aq.png)

Logs from submitList:

```
2022-05-26 17:57:30.314 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:165:submitList: Are the two lists the same? true
2022-05-26 17:57:30.315 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:168:submitList: Old list (size: 1): [Reminder(id=51, hour=21, minute=21)]
2022-05-26 17:57:30.315 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:169:submitList: New list (size: 1): [Reminder(id=51, hour=21, minute=21)]
```

If I click on the time again from my RecyclerView Item, the TimePickerDialog correctly defaults the time to 21:21 (so somewhere it knows the time was updated...) If I change the time to 18:21, as soon as I hit OK, the time updates:
[Picture of RecyclerView Item whose time was updated correctly to 18:21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LAOj.png)

Logs from submitList:

```
2022-05-26 18:03:50.931 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:165:submitList: Are the two lists the same? false
2022-05-26 18:03:50.932 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:168:submitList: Old list (size: 1): [Reminder(id=51, hour=21, minute=21)]
2022-05-26 18:03:50.932 6461-6461/com.example.ewmreminders V/ReminderListAdapter:169:submitList: New list (size: 1): [Reminder(id=51, hour=18, minute=21)]
```

**Code**:
Adapter:

```
class ReminderListAdapter(private val timeClickListener: ReminderClickListener,
                          private val reminderListViewModel: ReminderListViewModel,
                          val activity: MainActivity,
                          val reminderDatabaseDao: ReminderDatabaseDao):
    ListAdapter<Reminder, ReminderListAdapter.ReminderListViewHolder>(DiffCallback),
    ItemTouchHelperAdapter
{
    private var mRemindersList = mutableListOf<Reminder>()

    override fun submitList(list: List<Reminder>?) {
        Timber.v("Are the two lists the same? ${mRemindersList == list?.toMutableList()}")
        Timber.v("Old list (size: ${mRemindersList.size}): $mRemindersList")
        Timber.v("New list (size: ${list?.size}): $list")

        mRemindersList = list.toMutableList() //DiffUtil needs a new list to compare to
        super.submitList(mRemindersList)
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class ReminderListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var reminderListViewModel: ReminderListViewModel
    lateinit var adapter: ReminderListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding: FragmentReminderListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_reminder_list, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val reminderDatabaseDao = ReminderDatabase.getInstance(application).reminderDatabaseDao
        val viewModelFactory = ReminderListViewModelFactory(reminderDatabaseDao, application)
        reminderListViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[ReminderListViewModel::class.java] //.get() and [] are the same thing
        binding.reminderListViewModel = reminderListViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        binding.remindersList.layoutManager = manager
        
        adapter = ReminderListAdapter(
            ReminderClickListener(application) { reminder, position ->
                val defaultReminderTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(reminder.hour!!, reminder.minute!!)
                val timeClickListener =
                    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
                        val selectedTime = LocalTime.of(hourOfDay, minute)
                        reminderListViewModel.setTime(reminder, selectedTime) //updates the database
//                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
                    }
                val tP = TimePickerDialogPlus(context, timeClickListener, defaultReminderTime.hour, defaultReminderTime.minute, true) {
                    Timber.v("User clicked the Clear button")
                    reminderListViewModel.setTime(reminder, null)
                }
                tP.show()
            },
            reminderListViewModel,
            activity as MainActivity,
            reminderDatabaseDao)
        binding.remindersList.adapter = adapter
        
        reminderListViewModel.reminders.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it.toMutableList())
            }
        })
        
        return binding.root
        }
}
```

View Model:

```
class ReminderListViewModel(val reminderDatabaseDao: ReminderDatabaseDao, application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun setTime(reminder: Reminder, selectedTime: LocalTime?) {
        reminder.hour = selectedTime?.hour
        reminder.minute = selectedTime?.minute
        reminder.save(getApplication()) //eventually calls reminderDatabaseDao.update
    }
    var reminders = reminderDatabaseDao.getAllReminders()
}
```

Dao:

```
interface ReminderDatabaseDao {
    @Update
    fun update(reminder: Reminder)

    @Query("select * ...etc...")
    fun getAllReminders() : LiveData<List<Reminder>>
}
```

**Thought**

- I tried calling adapter.notifyItemChanged(position) but that didn't change anything

Comment: You haven't posted how you're updating `reminders` in your VM, but if your adapter's internal list is already updated when ``submitList`` is called (according to your logs) then that implies you're updating a `Reminder` object that both lists hold a reference to. As in, the lists may be completely different, but they contain the same object, and when you change that object in one place the other place sees that change too. You need to be creating new `Reminder` instances when you update a list's contents, or `DiffUtil` won't work when you modify an item like this

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks for your thought. I added relevant VM and Dao code. If your explanation was true, wouldn't that mean the adapter's list should always be the same as the `reminders` LiveData? If so, I would expect to always experience this problem, not only half the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah see, in your `setTime` function in the VM, you're passing in a `Reminder` instance and changing its data, mutating the object itself:

```
fun setTime(reminder: Reminder, selectedTime: LocalTime?) {
    reminder.hour = selectedTime?.hour
    reminder.minute = selectedTime?.minute
```

and the `Reminder` you're passing in is *one of the objects in the adapter's internal list*:

```
adapter = ReminderListAdapter(
    ReminderClickListener(application) { reminder, position ->
        ...
        reminderListViewModel.setTime(reminder, selectedTime)
```

So you're explicitly updating the `Reminder` in your adapter to *21:21* (which won't visually update because the adapter doesn't know anything about the change yet).

---

After `setTime` changes that `Reminder` object, it uses it to update the DB:

```
reminder.save(getApplication())
```

Which updates the record, which pushes a new list to the `LiveData` you grabbed with `getAllReminders()`, and that should contain unique `Reminder` instances. But remember, *you already changed the adapter's internal list* by updating that `Reminder`. The list you get from the DB is going to be the same as the old one, just with one of the `Reminder`s' time changed, right?

Since you changed the adapter's internal list in the same way, the data is gonna match - the lists will look the same (I'm assuming your diff treats two `Reminder`s with the same data as "the same", if they're data classes and checked for equality then yep). So the adapter doesn't bother updating the display - as far as it's concerned, nothing has changed.

---

Your dialog shows the correct time because the time *has been set* on that `Reminder` - the adapter just isn't showing it yet. I don't know why it would work every 2nd time with the exact same steps though - you'll probably need to set some breakpoints in useful places (e.g. in `setTime`, your observer on `reminders`, inside your dialog) and debug the app, see what's actually going on in there as it's running.

---

Sorry about the long answer but I wanted to explain why you're seeing that issue - you're effectively updating the adapter's internal list *and* the one in the DB/View Model at the same time, so they always match. You can probably fix it by *not* mutating the `Reminder` you pass in - just make a copy, change the time on it, and save *that* to the DB. Leave the old one untouched, so it reflects the old state. If you're using a data class, you can just do

```
reminder.copy(
    hour = selectedTime?.hour,
    minute = selectedTime?.minute
).save(application) // if you make application a val in your VM constructor you can access it here
```

and that might fix everything!

Comment: You're totally correct, editing the copied `Reminder` fixed it. The internal workings of the RecyclerView.Adapter class were a mystery to me and I never realized I was passing back a pointer to the same data. You've really made my day; thanks for the great explanation @cactustictacs!